# binary search to compute maximum value of t(a variable) in inequalities

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

How can we use binary search to solve the given inequalities where we need to find the maximum value for t. The values of RED,BLUE AND GREEN (WE HAVE USED R,B,G to denote is) already known.

```
  Min(R, G, B) >= t * x and
  R + G + B - 3 * x * t >= t.
```

Here X can be assumed to be known .SO how do apply binary search algorithm to determine the maximum  value of t.
A pseudo code will also work.

Comment: "A pseudo code will also work". Good to know! Are we doing your homework for you?

Comment: @nicomp No, we're interviewing for a job. :) I hope we get it!!

Comment: What is the range of `t`? Is it `[0,1]`?

Comment: Why use binary search when the maximum can be computed directly using basic math?

Comment: @KlasLindbäck This is what I was thinking, however for the specific solution it might be helpful if the ranges of the values could be known.

Comment: @Codor: it simplifies things to know whether you multiply/divide by something less than zero when tranforming the inequalities because it changes the inequality from `>=` to `<=`, but that check can be made with a simple if.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Exactly.

Comment: So you're interviewing for a job and you can't do the work?  I trust you will link to this question in the code/pseudo code you submit. ;)

Comment: @nicomp i came across this problem on a competitive programming website and i couldn't come up with a correct approach to solve this and yes,it is not from a present contest so seeking help on stack overflow .